# Python wait until?

Tags: python

I am getting data from a previously requested url. Everything works so far.

My problem:
I try to make a query every X seconds and if the query shows a different value, something should be done. But it prints Solving-Capture even when finalresponseback != notready

> ```
>  responseback = requests.get('https://2captcha.com/res.php?json=1&action=get&key=' + apikey + "&id=" + finalrequest)
> ```

```
 responseback_json = responseback.json()
 finalresponseback = responseback_json['request']
 print(responseback_json)
 notready = (str("CAPCHA_NOT_READY"))



 while(finalresponseback == notready):
     print("Solving-Capture...")
     if finalresponseback != notready:
         print("Entering...")
```

Comment: Please write down your code instead of sharing picture.

Comment: Did you  try `time.sleep()`? I think in this way you can make gap between each query every X seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the way you have writen your code,
let's say that finalresponseback is not ready, then this would happen:

```py
while(finalresponseback == notready): # This would enable the loop because it's equal to not ready
    print("Solving-Capture...") # It would print this
    if finalresponseback != notready: # Nothing would happen because it is equal to notready
        print("Entering...") # This woudln't happen
```

However, if suddenly it changes:

```py
while(finalresponseback == notready): # This happened before it changed
    print("Solving-Capture...") # This also happened before it changed, so it happens anyway
    if finalresponseback != notready: # This happens too
        print("Entering...") # And so does this, so therefore it would print both statements
```

This code is bad because if it changes to not be notready, then it would exit the loop witrhout doing anything unless it changes while in the loop, a better version of this would be:

```py
while(1): # Starts a loop
    if finalresponseback != notready: # Checks finalresponseback
        print("Entering...") # Prints statement
        break # Exits loop
    else: # If it is equal to notready
        print("Solving-Capture...") # Print statement
```

The code directly above checks the finalresponseback within the loop, and therefore, it will be able to print the statement rather than exiting entirely at the start like before.

And lastly, we can add the:

```py
responseback_json = responseback.json()
finalresponseback = responseback_json['request']
```

to the code to request every x seconds as so:

```py
import time # Add to top of code, imports the time library
x = 2 # Sets the x variable
while(1): # Starts a loop
    responseback_json = responseback.json()
    finalresponseback = responseback_json['request']
    if finalresponseback != notready: # Checks finalresponseback
        print("Entering...") # Prints statement
        break # Exits loop
    else: # If it is equal to notready
        print("Solving-Capture...") # Print statement
    time.sleep(x)
```

And lastly, a tip to optimize your code, instead of

```py
notready = (str("CAPCHA_NOT_READY"))
```

You can do

```py
notready = "CAPCHA_NOT_READY"
```

This is because it is already a string value (as indicated by the speech marks "")